# Rails: Conditionally enable / disable devise modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building my own dynamic backend in top of Ruby on Rails framework. I would like to know if there is a way to conditionally enable or disable Devise modules such as registerable, confirmable, omniauthable, ...

What I did try almost worked except I had to restart the rails server to take in consideration my modification but in my case I would like the system to work with boolean defined in the database.

**For example**:

```
devise :registerable if registerable_module.enabled? # boolean fetched from database
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to alter this on the fly, in the running process? What for?

Comment: As a super administrator I want to be able to enable or disable devise modules depending of my clients request directly from the database. Is it possible ?

Comment: There's app per client?

Comment: Why do you ask that ? I think my question is pretty clear. Do you know if it is possible or not ? Thank you

Comment: If I have to ask, then your question is _not_ clear. Obvious, isn't it? But if you're looking for one-word answer, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: I need an answer to this also. Basically what I have is that a user is created upon a booking, but they have to tick an option to actually allow creating a user, and only that latter type of user is an actual user

Comment: I have a smilar case, but with ldap module which I want to enable/disable from UI administration to either use database or LDAP.